# Show this set can't be precompact via counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $I=[0,1]$ and $B=\{u\in\mathcal{C}^{1}(I,\mathbb{R})\mid \|u'\|_{L^{2}(I)}\leq1\}$, then it can be easily shown $B$ is an equicontinous family of functions. Now, how  do we find a counterexample, i.e. a sequence $u_{n}$ which doesn't have converging subsequences, thus deducing it is not relatively compact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but can't you just take the sequence of constant functions $u_n\equiv n $?

Comment: I was thinking something more complicated, but your idea seems to br working.

Comment: By the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem, $B$ is relatively compact if and only if it is equicontinuous and bounded.  The condition $\|u'\|_{L^{2}(I)} \leq 1$ only constrains $u'$; it says nothing about $u$, and, in fact, is unchanged if we add any constant to $u$.  Notice that if $u \in B$, then $u + n \in B$ also holds and $\|u +n\|_{L^{\infty}(I)} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.